# hacer login y registro en java y sql

Tags: java, jdbc

hola quien me puede ayudar a hacer un login y registro en java usando base de datos al igual que el intercambio de ventanas no funciona 
estoy usando xampp

```
package login;


import Control_BD.fusuario;
import Principal.Conexion;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;




/**
 *
 * @author CARLOS
 */
public class frmusuariologin extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    /**
     * Creates new form frmusuariologin
     */
    public frmusuariologin() {
        initComponents();
       this.setTitle("Acceso al Sistema");
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtusuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtpassword = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        btningresar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnsalir = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablalistado = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButtonRegistrar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 153, 255));

        jLabel1.setText("Usuario:");

        jLabel2.setText("Password:");

        btningresar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
        btningresar.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        btningresar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Files/guardar.png"))); // NOI18N
        btningresar.setText("Ingresar");
        btningresar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btningresarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnsalir.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
        btnsalir.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        btnsalir.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Files/salir.gif"))); // NOI18N
        btnsalir.setText("Salir");
        btnsalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnsalirActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tablalistado.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablalistado);

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Files/usuario.png"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel4.setText("Si no estas registrado picha en registrar ");

        jButtonRegistrar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jButtonRegistrar.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButtonRegistrar.setText("Registrar");
        jButtonRegistrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonRegistrarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(btningresar))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(btnsalir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(txtusuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 199, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtpassword))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 98, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButtonRegistrar)
                .addGap(85, 85, 85))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addComponent(txtusuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addComponent(txtpassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(btningresar)
                                    .addComponent(btnsalir)))))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 148, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButtonRegistrar)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btningresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            DefaultTableModel modelo;
            fusuario func =new fusuario();

            modelo=func.login(txtusuario.getText(),txtpassword.getText());
            tablalistado.setModel(modelo);
            if (func.totalregistros >0) {
                this.dispose();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Se logueo correctamente", null, WIDTH, null);


                if (!tablalistado.getValueAt(0, 3).toString().equals("Administrador")) {

                }
                  if (!tablalistado.getValueAt(0, 3).toString().equals("Empleado")) {
                }



            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Acceso Denegado","Acceso al Sistema",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }                                           

    private void btnsalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

System.exit(0);
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButtonRegistrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
ViewRegistro registro= new ViewRegistro; 
registro.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
    }                                                

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmusuariologin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmusuariologin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmusuariologin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmusuariologin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new frmusuariologin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btningresar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnsalir;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonRegistrar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablalistado;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtpassword;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtusuario;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}

//

package Control_BD;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author richard
 */
public class fusuario {



//incializamos la coneccion    
        Connection cn = null;
 //   private ConexionConBaseDatos mysql = new conexion();
//creamos las variables
    private String sSQL = "";//para la consulta sql
    private String sSQL2 = "";//para otra consulta sql
    public Integer totalregistros;//guarda e total de los registros de una tabla


  //creamos la funcion que nos va evaluar si el usuario existe
    // va ser tipo DefaultTableModel y va recibir dos paramtros
    public DefaultTableModel login(String usuario,String contraseña) {
        cn=conection.getConexion();
        DefaultTableModel modelo;

        String[] titulos = {"id_usuario", "nombre_usuario", "contraseña_usuario"};
//creamos un areglo registro con el cual sacaremos los datos de la base de datos
        String[] registro = new String[10];
//inicializamos totalregistros
        totalregistros = 0;
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);//inicializamos modelo
//escribimos la consulta en nuestro string sql
        sSQL = "select id_usuario,contraseña_usuario,email,nombre_usuario"
                + " from usuario_datos_galeria_db "
                + " where nombre_usuario='"
                + usuario + "' and contraseña_usuario='" + contraseña + "'";
//CREAMOS EL TRY CACH pra que no nos controlar los errores
        try {
            //creamos una varibale Statement que nos serivra para ejecutar una consulta sql
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            //ejecutamos la consulta u la guardamos en un ResultSet
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);
//ahora el sacamos los registros del resulset con con while
            while (rs.next()) {
                //guardamos los registros en el areglo registros
                //posicion por posicion cada tabla
                registro[0] = rs.getString("id_usuario");
                registro[1] = rs.getString("nombre_usuario");
                registro[2] = rs.getString("contraseña_usuario");


                //contamos el total de registros de la consulta
                totalregistros = totalregistros + 1;
                modelo.addRow(registro);//agregamos al modelo para sacar los datos

            }
            return modelo;//devolvemos el modelo

        } //cach controla los errores que puedan suceder
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, en vez de poner todo el código de tu programa. Podrías poner la parte donde salta el error? E indicarnos también que error te está dando?

Comment: Cuidado con las `ñ`, puede provocar errores muy graves de los que no te darás cuenta qué le pasa al programa.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar apache shiro, es un framework para hacer login de aplicaciones de escritorio: https://shiro.apache.org/